# Stellarium 0.18.0 spontaneously crashing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I'm having a bit of a problem with Stellarium on Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I open Stellarium it seems to work only for a couple of second (quite normally and smoothly without any lagging) before abruptly closing down without any error messages at all. This happened both with stellarium installed through Ubuntu Software Center and through terminal. I have made sure that each installation was clean by removing Stellarium completely with Synaptic Package Manager.

This is the output generated when I run Stellarium through terminal:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
[ This is Stellarium 0.18.1 - http://www.stellarium.org ]
[ Copyright (C) 2000-2018 Fabien Chereau et al.         ]
 -------------------------------------------------------
Writing log file to: "/home/neitz/.stellarium/log.txt"
File search paths:
  0 .  "/home/neitz/.stellarium"
  1 .  "/usr/share/stellarium"
Config file is:  "/home/neitz/.stellarium/config.ini"
Default surface format:  QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior 0, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
Desired surface format:  QSurfaceFormat(version 2.1, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 0, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
StelGLWidget constructor
StelGraphicsScene constructor
initializeGL
OpenGL supported version:  "3.0 Mesa 18.0.5"
Current Format:  QSurfaceFormat(version 3.0, options QFlags(0x4), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 0, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
StelMainView::init
Detected: OpenGL "3.0"
Driver version string: "3.0 Mesa 18.0.5"
GL vendor is "Intel Open Source Technology Center"
GL renderer is "Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) "
GL Shading Language version is "1.30"
MESA Version Number detected:  18
Mesa version is fine, we should not see a graphics problem.
GLSL Version Number detected:  1.3
GLSL version is fine, we should not see a graphics problem.
Cache directory is:  "/home/neitz/.cache/stellarium/stellarium"
Sky language is  "en_US"
Planetary features language is  "en_US"
Application language is  "en_US"
Loading Solar System data (1: planets and moons) ...
Loading from : "/usr/share/stellarium/data/ssystem_major.ini"
Loaded 77 Solar System bodies
Loading Solar System data (2: minor bodies)...
Loading from : "/home/neitz/.stellarium/data/ssystem_minor.ini"
Loaded 102 Solar System bodies
File ssystem_minor.ini is loaded successfully...
Loading nomenclature for Solar system bodies ...
Loaded 15505 / 15510 items of planetary surface nomenclature
Loading star data ...
"Loading /usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/stars_0_0v0_7.cat: 0_0v0_7; 4979"
"Loading /usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/stars_1_0v0_7.cat: 1_0v0_7; 21806"
"Loading /usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/stars_2_0v0_7.cat: 2_0v0_7; 150850"
"Loading /usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/stars_3_1v0_4.cat: 3_1v0_4; 425807"
Finished loading star catalogue data, max_geodesic_level:  3
Loading scientific star names from "/usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/name.fab"
Loaded 4506 / 4506 scientific star names
Loading variable stars from "/usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/gcvs_hip_part.dat"
Loaded 6916 / 6916 variable stars
Loading double stars from "/usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/wds_hip_part.dat"
Loaded 16412 / 16412 double stars
Loading cross-identification data from "/usr/share/stellarium/stars/default/cross-id.dat"
Loaded 108338 / 108338 cross-identification data records for stars
navigation/preset_sky_time is a double - treating as jday: "2451514.25001"
Loading DSO data ...
[...] "Stellarium DSO Catalog, version 3.5 (standard edition)"
Loaded 90415 DSO records
Loading DSO outline data ...
Loaded 63 DSO outline records successfully
LandscapeMgr: initialized Cache for 100 MB.
Loading star names from "/usr/share/stellarium/skycultures/western/star_names.fab"
Loaded 860 / 860 common star names
Loading DSO name data ...
Loaded 1012 / 1029 DSO name records successfully
WARNING - No position data for 17 objects: "PGC 621, PGC 2345, PGC 2906, PGC 2907, PGC 14098, PGC 23521, PGC 28759, PGC 29167, PGC 34658, PGC 42102, PGC 54559, PGC 59117, PGC 73957, PGC 95597, PGC 100170, PGC 100170, PGC 119230"
Loaded 88 / 88 constellation records successfully for culture "western"
Loaded 85 / 85 constellation art records successfully for culture "western"
Loaded 88 / 88 constellation names
Loading constellation boundary data ... 
Loaded 782 constellation boundary segments
Error in Asterism  "TA6" : can't find star with coordinates 2.14697 / 8.55097
ERROR reading asterism lines record at line  63 for culture "western"
Loaded 53 / 54 asterism records successfully for culture "western"
WARNING - asterism abbreviation "TA6" not found when loading asterism names
Loaded 43 / 44 asterism names
stel.OpenGLArray: Disabling VAO usage because of Intel driver bugs
stel.OpenGLArray: Vertex Array Objects are not supported on your hardware (this is not an error)
Initializing basic GL shaders... 
Creating GUI ...
Loaded plugin "Exoplanets"
[Exoplanets] File format is wrong! Error: illegal value
[Exoplanets] Default exoplanets.json to  "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/Exoplanets/exoplanets.json"
[Exoplanets] loading catalog file: "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/Exoplanets/exoplanets.json"
Loaded plugin "FOV"
Loaded plugin "MeteorShowers"
MeteorShowersMgr: Loading catalog file: "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/MeteorShowers/showers.json"
Loaded plugin "Novae"
[Novae] version of the catalog: 1
[Novae] loading catalog file: "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/Novae/novae.json"
Loaded plugin "Oculars"
Ocular plugin - press Command-O to toggle eyepiece view mode. Press ALT-o for configuration.
Oculars::validateIniFile ocular.ini exists at:  "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/Oculars/ocular.ini" . Checking version...
Oculars::validateIniFile found existing ini file version  3.1
Loaded plugin "Satellites"
[Satellites] loading catalog file: "/home/neitz/.stellarium/modules/Satellites/satellites.json"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "MOLNIYA 3-3" "08425"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "IRIDIUM 6" "24794"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "IRIDIUM 19" "24965"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "IRIDIUM 34" "24969"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "IRIDIUM 43" "25039"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "IRIDIUM 40" "25041"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "GRACE-1" "27391"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "GRACE-2" "27392"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "ORS 1" "37728"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "TIANGONG 1" "37820"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "EAGLE 2" "39436"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "AGGIESAT 4" "41313"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-1" "41479"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-2" "41481"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-2" "41484"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-4" "41487"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-6" "41563"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-8" "41569"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-9" "41571"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-12" "41573"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E-11" "41574"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-9" "41575"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-10" "41576"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-12" "41578"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "FLOCK 2E'-13" "41761"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "STARS-C" "41895"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "OSNSAT" "41939"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "LEMUR-2-TRUTNA" "42067"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "Columbia" "42702"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "ISS DEB (ROSA)" "42813"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "TECHEDSAT 6" "43026"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "DRAGON CRS-13 DEB" "43061"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "DRAGON CRS-13 DEB" "43062"
Satellite has invalid orbit: "SL-4 R/B" "43064"
Loaded plugin "SolarSystemEditor"
Using the ssystem_minor.ini file that already exists in the user directory...
Dubious result: Landscape  "Guereins"  not calibrated. Opacity test represents mathematical horizon only.
Initializing planets GL shaders... 
[Exoplanets] Starting update...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  illegal value
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I see that the program terminates after `std::runtime_error`. Any ideas on why this is the case and how to fix it?

Thanks to anyone attempting this problem in advance!

Comment: The same thing happens on 18.04.

Comment: I have not been able to get stellarium to run for some time now. It used to work when I set it to software rendering with "LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 stellarium" but now even that is failing. They are obviously doing something non-standard as there are plenty of 3d games from steam that works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url for Stellarium.org (and the JSON files the program looks to for updates) has changed.
Find your config.ini file and edit the 3 instances of "http://stellarium.org/json/. . . " to read "https://www.stellarium.org/json/. . . " instead.

EDIT JULY 31,2018:
 . . . and apparently the urls for those JSON files have changed back again. If you used the config.ini edit workaround mentioned above it is broken again. Revert back to the original urls to fix it - again (perhaps just restore config.ini from config.old?)
Looks like any data update call from a bad url writes the html error return into a new "JSON" file, then when the program loads the module and tries to read data from that corrupted JSON file it crashes. Which then triggers another update attempt on the next restart attempt. Next thing you know even your old backup copy of the JSON file is overwritten with the html error.

Comment: reference the bug report (and comments) at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stellarium/+bug/1783321

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem. Thank you @Wilfred!

Comment: Sadly, it still crashed for me on 18.04 even if I do this.  But when I deleted the .stellarium directory, then started the program, it now works, even with the old urls in the config file.